# Button is not switching from disabled to enabled

Tags: c#, wpf

I finally got rid of all the error messages as I attempted ways to find a control and enable it.

In the properties pane I disabled a button on mainwindow.

This code runs successfully, albeit annoyingly, because every second I have it give me another msgbox to show code is being triggered. But it is not enabling the button. I'm new to C# so it looks like arabic to me. In VB it would just be:

```
btnMyButton.Enabled = True
```

Here is my code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 ms is one second
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    public void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
       DateTime today3am = now.Date.AddHours(3);

       if (DateTime.Today == today3am.Date && now >= today3am)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Code is being triggered");
          btnMyButton.IsEnabled = true;
       }
    }
}
```

SOLVED: Response suggested this: (IT WORKED)

```
public void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime today3am = now.Date.AddHours(3);

    if (DateTime.Today == today3am.Date && now >= today3am)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button Should Enable");
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            btnMyButton.IsEnabled = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copy and paste the code you've provided and run it, I get (as expected) an exception when trying to set the `IsEnabled` property:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

This is the standard "wrong thread" exception. You don't see the exception (apparently) because you're not running in a debugger. The `Timer` thread catches the exception and ignores it.

One way to fix the problem is to, as suggested by others, use `Dispatcher.Invoke()`:

```
public void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime today3am = now.Date.AddHours(3);

    if (DateTime.Today == today3am.Date && now >= today3am)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => btnMyButton.IsEnabled = true);
    }
}
```

However, since the problem is fundamentally caused by your use of the `System.Timers.Timer` class, it makes more sense to just use the correct timer class, `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    myTimer.Tick += DisplayTimeEvent;
    myTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    myTimer.Start();
}

public void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime today3am = now.Date.AddHours(3);

    if (DateTime.Today == today3am.Date && now >= today3am)
    {
        btnMyButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. When I first made the attempt to add a timer I saw both options as quick fix. I did the 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer' first and then also added a using statement for the timer class. I am a complete noob lol. I do appreciate you taking the time to explain it to me. I will be sure to read more about this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Dispatcher`. It may be that the GUI blocks up the change of controls from Code. The `Dispatcher` coordinates the access to an element from multiple threads:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    btnMyButton.IsEnabled = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Now, I'll have to learn about the various threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the property on the Dispatcher thread as you are not on the UI thread in the event handler